# ASIHTTPRequest UIProgressView don´t work

Tags: ios, progress-bar, asihttprequest, uiprogressview

I´m new in Xcode and have a problem with `UIProgressView`.
I found some code but I don't understand it well. Could you please explain me why `UIProgressView` is not closing after finish?

```
- (IBAction)Download:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://db.tt/5WP2pia"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 80.0f, 225.0f, 90.0f)];
    UIAlertView *progressAlert =
            [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Download..." 
                                       message: @"Please wait..."
                                      delegate: self
                             cancelButtonTitle: nil 
                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [progressAlert addSubview:progressView];
    [progressView setProgressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/var/root/osk.rar"];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
    [progressAlert show];
    [progressAlert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to manually close the alert, after `ASIHTTPRequest` is done. `progressView != progressAlert`
2. Don't use `ASIHTTPRequest`